# Salvar estado em localStorage

Tags: react, typescript

Preciso salvar um estado (que é uma lista de objetos) em um localStorage, mas o primeiro valor sempre é "[]", porque inicializei o estado dessa forma.

```
const [favorites, setFavorites] = useState<IPodcast[]>([]);
```

No localStorage fica assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu preciso que o primeiro valor salvo no localStorage seja o primeiro valor da minha lista. Segue abaixo o código responsável por salvar o estado no localStorage.

```
function adicionarFavorito(evento: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
    evento.preventDefault();
    podcastList.filter((p) => p.id === idPodcast)
    .map((p) => (setFavorites((oldFavorites) => [...oldFavorites, { ...podcastList[p.num] }])));
    localStorage.setItem("favorites", JSON.stringify(favorites));
}
```

Como posso fazer o que preciso?

Answer (score -2):

Cara tenta verificar se o seu Map vai ter informação ou não .
Caso tenha informação você inseri, se não retorna null algo do tipo.

adiciona isso no final do código

```
podcastList.length ? localStorage.setItem("favorites", JSON.stringify(favorites)); : null;
```

e testa.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).